# How do you tell Wordpress to ignore a folder, in favor of a permalink?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a client who had a non-WordPress site, with a WordPress blog located in a subfolder `/blog/`. We launched them a new WordPress site in the root. Unfortunately, all the images in their blog posts are still pointing at `/blog/wp-content/uploads/`. I want to just add all these images to a subfolder on the file tree at `/blog/wp-content/uploads`, so it will just automagically fix all those broken images without extra work from me.

The problem is that their new blog page is located at `/blog/`. I can't change this for SEO reasons. If I move the images, then navigating to `/blog/` doesn't show the WordPress page, it shows a folder on the file tree.

I want it to show the WordPress page instead. Is there a way to tell WordPress to ignore that folder, and show the WordPress page when `/blog/` is called instead?

Comment: I assume sub pages do work OK, it's just the WP home page that does not?

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress *front controller* only routes the request when you don't request a physical file or directory on the file system. The problem here is that when you create a physical directory called `/blog` then WP will no longer route the request and you see the directory.

*Aside:* You shouldn't really be seeing the directory contents, ideally you should get a 403 Forbidden. Add `Options -Indexes` to the top of your `.htaccess` file.

The default WP `.htaccess` contains the following lines that excludes physical files and directories from being routed (ie. so that static resources can be accessed).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

You can make an exception for the `/blog` subdirectory by changing this to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/?$
```